# Do i need the 32 bit or 64 bit version of Mysql for use with php 5.5

Tags: macos, mysql, php

First time Mac user, I am just about to download MySQL for Mac, which version do I need for use with PHP 5.5? Apologies if this is a really simple question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your Mac is 64 bit, the 64-bit version would be preferred. If you are on a 32-bit system, you'll have no choice but to go with the 32-bit version. See the [How to tell if your Intel-based Mac has a 32-bit or 64-bit processor](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3696) to determine what you are running.